# Weird behavior with busybox grep and wget in alpine linux

Tags: shell, grep, alpine-linux, busybox, ash

I'm trying to grep a string from `wget --help`, I want to check if implementation of wget support my desired option.

```
wget --help | grep -q '\--show-progress'
```

I expect if the command failed, it will return non-zero exit code-- this is my intention. But executing this on Alpine Linux 3.13 give following result.

```
~ # wget --help | grep -q '\--show-progress'
BusyBox v1.32.1 () multi-call binary.

Usage: wget [-c|--continue] [--spider] [-q|--quiet] [-O|--output-document FILE]
        [-o|--output-file FILE] [--header 'header: value'] [-Y|--proxy on/off]
        [-P DIR] [-S|--server-response] [-U|--user-agent AGENT] [-T SEC] URL...

Retrieve files via HTTP or FTP

        --spider        Only check URL existence: $? is 0 if exists
        -c              Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
        -q              Quiet
        -P DIR          Save to DIR (default .)
        -S              Show server response
        -T SEC          Network read timeout is SEC seconds
        -O FILE         Save to FILE ('-' for stdout)
        -o FILE         Log messages to FILE
        -U STR          Use STR for User-Agent header
        -Y on/off       Use proxy
~ #
```

No matter what I do, it still print the whole `--help` section. Is there any workaround ? Im using Alpine Linux 3.13

Comment: Try `wget --help 2>&1 | grep -- '--show-progress'` and see [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283739/1765658)

Comment: Thanks, it works beautifully. But what about if I insert valid (exist) character, for example `Only`, it print `        --spider        Only check URL existence: $? is 0 if exists`. Anyway to suppress that too and just get exit code?

Comment: `wget --help 2>&1 | grep -q -- '--show-progress'`

Comment: Holy, I completely forgot that. Thank you !